# Should this ping question, where the OP was using improper syntax, really be closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, closed-questions

This question is about how to use ping properly:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/159921/why-cant-i-ping-http-ushou-appeng01-ufm

The user is **not** asking:

- why a particular site does not respond to pings. The OP expected that it should, and that the problem is on the client machine. The OP was correct (though the problem was that the `ping` command was being used incorrectly on the client machine).
- why a ping might not succeed in general.
- how to configure a non-Ubuntu system to respond to pings.

Instead, the question is about why a particular ping command produced a particular error. And the information that has been provided in comments actually answers the question (and should be given as an answer).

Can anyone explain why it is correct for this to have been closed as *off-topic*?

If not, I'd suggest it ought to be reopened.

**It seems to me that this was closed because it appeared that the OP was asking why a particular site does not respond to pings. Since that's not really what the question is about, and it is instead about how to use Ubuntu's ping command, I recommend this be reopened.**

Comment: I concur with this. The question should be reopened as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is not sufficient community motivation to reopen this, so I guess the consensus is that it should stay closed.

I still think it should be reopened, but I believe I'm in the minority. If others believe it should be reopened, you can go ahead and reopen-vote it (if you have enough reputation to cast close and reopen votes), and/or post a new answer here, and/or comment or ping me in chat to ask me to unaccept this meta answer.

Otherwise, I feel comfortable saying that its closure is consistent with the wishes of the community, and does not need to change.

Comment: That one looks abandoned to me, plus it's tough to motivate (even four) people to vote to re-open. Why not ask a new question on how to correctly ping? It's on topic and, assuming no dupes already, should be covered here.

Comment: @TomBrossman That's a good idea. I may do that sometime soon. (It would be an ask-and-answer-at-the-same-time kind of thing.)